# Why is my python test loop not completing?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to develop a stock back tester.  The sequence is as follows:

1. Iterate through a pandas dataframe.
2. When buy signal == 1, debit the closing cost from the account.
3. Add log returns for every position after until...
4. Sell signal == 1
5. Credit the closing cost from that observation
6. Stop summing the log returns
7. Repeat steps 1 - 6 until the end of the data frame.

This is the code I used:

```
def back_test(df):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    df : dataframe
    starting_value : portfolio value
    pct_cash : percentage you want to remain in cash

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """

    account_balance_strategy = 0
    

    return_strategy = 0
    
    df  = df.copy()
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    
    condition = [(df['predicted_RSI_indicator'] > .94)]
    replace = [1]
    df['buy_open'] = np.select(condition,replace, default = 0)
    
    buy_open_signal = (df['buy_open'] == 1) & (df['buy_open'].shift(1) == 0)
    
    condition = [(df['predicted_RSI_indicator'] <= .94)]
    replace = [1]
    df['sell_close'] = np.select(condition,replace, default = 0)
    
    buy_open_signal = (df['buy_open'] == 1) & (df['buy_open'].shift(1)==0)
    sell_close_signal = (df['sell_close'] == 1) & (df['sell_close'].shift(1)==0)
                                              
    position = 0
    for ts, row in df.iterrows():
        print(position, ts)
        while position == 0:
            if (row['buy_open'] == 1) and (position == 0):
                account_balance_strategy -= row['adjusted_close']
                postion = 1
                return_strategy += row['log_return']
        while position == 1:
            print(position, ts)
            return_strategy += row['log_return']
            if (row['predicted_RSI_indicator'] < .95):
                account_balance += row['adjusted_close']
                position = 0
                
    print(return_strategy, account_balance_strategy)
```

This code prints the first time frame index and position.  Then it runs until I cancel it.  So something is not closed somewhere.  Does anyone see my loop mistake?  Or is there a better way other than a loop to accomplish the steps?

UPDATE/ANSWER:

it was the `while` loop causing the iterator to never make it past the first row. Here is what ended up working.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May 10 14:50:27 2021

@author: Jordan Howell
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np




def back_test(df):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    df : dataframe
    starting_value : portfolio value
    pct_cash : percentage you want to remain in cash

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    account_balance_hold = 0
    account_balance_strategy = 0
    
    return_hold = 0
    return_strategy = 0
    
    df  = df.copy()
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    
    condition = [(df['predicted_RSI_indicator'] > .94)]
    replace = [1]
    df['buy_open'] = np.select(condition,replace, default = 0)
    
    buy_open_signal = (df['buy_open'] == 1) & (df['buy_open'].shift(1) == 0)
    
    condition = [(df['predicted_RSI_indicator'] <= .94)]
    replace = [1]
    df['sell_close'] = np.select(condition,replace, default = 0)
    
    buy_open_signal = (df['buy_open'] == 1) & (df['buy_open'].shift(1)==0)
    sell_close_signal = (df['sell_close'] == 1) & (df['sell_close'].shift(1)==0)
                                               
    # condition =[(df['predicted_RSI_indicator'] > 17.85) & (df['predicted_RSI_indicator'] <36.7)]
    # replace =[1]
    # df['sell_open'] = np.select(condition,replace, default = 0)
    # sell_open_signal = (df['sell_open'] == 1) & (df['sell_open'].shift(1) == 0)
    
    
    position = 0
    for ts, row in df.iterrows():
        print(position, ts)
        position == 0
        if (row['buy_open'] != 1) and (position == 0):
            print(ts, row['buy_open'])
            
        elif (row['buy_open'] == 1) and (position == 0) :
            position = 1
            account_balance_strategy -= row['adjusted_close']
            print(position, ts, row['predicted_RSI_indicator'],
                  account_balance_hold)
            
            
        elif (position == 1):
            return_strategy += row['log_return']
            print(position, ts, row['predicted_RSI_indicator'],
                  return_strategy, account_balance_hold)
            
        elif (position == 1) & (row['predicted_RSI_indicator'] < .95):
            account_balance_strategy += row['adjusted_close']
            
            print(position, ts, row['predicted_RSI_indicator'],
                  return_strategy, account_balance_hold)
            break
    print(return_strategy, account_balance_strategy)
```

Comment: For one, there's a typo in `postion = 1`

Comment: You’re correct but it didn’t fix the issue.  Thank you though.

Comment: What if `row['buy_open'] != 1`? You enter the first `while` loop, check whether `row['buy_open'] == 1`. That's false, so you go to the next iteration of this `while` loop. Check whether `row['buy_open'] == 1` _again_. But _`row` never changed_! So `row['buy_open'] == 1` must be false forever since `row` never changes inside the loop

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try that. I know I have over 12k rows that meet the condition.

Comment: @ForceBru, oh.  I see what you're saying.  It's not iterating pass the first row.  Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: I think I may get it.  Take out the 'while' and just use 'if' statements.  I've updated the question.

Comment: @Shree  I will if it gets enough votes to reopen.  Until then, I can't.